# Jconsole remote Connection Lost: Reconnect?

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx, tomcat9, jconsole

I'm trying to make a jconsole remote monitoring of my tomcat 9 with java 8 jre (server adress: 192.168.10.3).
In tomcat9w i have this java options:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5000
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.10.3
```

Firewall is off.

Jconsole with -debug shows me this:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Expecting a sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef2 remote reference in stub!
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.checkStub(RMIConnector.java:1787)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:310)
    at jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:355)
    at jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:313)
    at jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:296)
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.getTotalMemorySize(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole.SummaryTab.formatSummary(SummaryTab.java:261)
    at jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole.SummaryTab$1.doInBackground(SummaryTab.java:87)
    at jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole.SummaryTab$1.doInBackground(SummaryTab.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:343)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException: No such attribute: TotalMemorySize
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.StandardMBean.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor95.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:164)
    at jdk.remoteref/jdk.jmx.remote.internal.rmi.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.getAttribute(RMIConnector.java:904)
    at jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient$SnapshotInvocationHandler.getAttribute(ProxyClient.java:1011)
    at jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient$SnapshotInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyClient.java:984)
    at jdk.proxy1/com.sun.proxy.jdk.proxy1.$Proxy1.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy$GetHandler.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:122)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:167)
    at java.management/javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:258)
    ... 10 more
```

So i can't tell what's wrong with my tomcat and java.
I read the tomcat documentation and found nothing there to help me solve this problem.

Comment: Try this. Change the values to what you're using. This is what is configured in my system and it works.

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010 
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1

Answer (score 8):

In my case I tried to run JConsole from openjdk-1.14 against a VM on openjdk-1.11 and got the same error.

Using a different JDK did the trick.